# Azure Devops maven build failing at sonar qube instance

Tags: maven, azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I recently downloaded the SonarQube demo from Devops official page. I used it a little bit and kind of left it there for a week.

No changes were made but when I came back today for showing how the sonarQube pipeline integration works, build fails.

From the logs, I see the following error

`Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project myshuttle: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password`

From there I tried adding username and password at the `Prepare analysis for sonar Qube stage` om advanced options (which was not necessary before) but the build keeps failing.

I think sonarQube was updated recently and the problem may be there. Issue is still weird because im following word by word the steps on setting up a sonarQube scan.

Any idea on what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update your sonarQube service connection.

You can go to your **Project settings** and click the **Service Connections** under **Pipelines**.

Select your sonarqube connection and click **update service connection** under **Actions**, Recopy your [SonarQube Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/) and click Ok. Please refer to below screenshot.

[image]